# How can i hide the play/pause button?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

As question suggested i want to hide the play/Pause button from "Youtube" player.
I am using 
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

and  setting the playerVars parameter like this:

```
 let playerVars = [
        "controls" : 0,
        "playsinline" : 1,
        "autohide" : 0,
        "showinfo" : 0,
        "modestbranding" : 0
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three parameters I found useful are:

```
showinfo=0
controls=0
autohide=1
```

`showinfo=0` makes sure the video does not display the title on the top of the video frame.

`controls=0` hides the bottom bar with the play button, volume, etc.

`autohide=1` hides the controls until you hover over them, which is probably the most useful.

[All the official docs are here.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

But you can use embed with custom CSS to hide or adjust he location of the Play button.

```
button.ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.  I am using the youtube-ios-player-helper pod.  how can i embed the custom css?

Comment: yes, I changed the YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html and updated css.